# How to parallel sending/processing to kafka topic/partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, kafka-producer-api

I have 1 flume agent (1 source, 1 channel, 1 sink) that reads data from specific directory (Spooldir) and send to Kafka Sink. Based on my observation it is just writing to specific partition.

What will be configuration to enable parallel send/processing to kafka topic/partition?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add another sink that uses your spooldir source and channel.

So something along the lines of:
Sink
- Channel 1
- Sink 1
- Sink 2

Not sure if you need another channel as you then might reread items from your spooldir source.

Answer (score 0):

By default events are distributed between partitions by `key` header. If you want to partition data yourself then you need to use interceptor which will set `partitionIdHeader`.

If you need to send data to multiple topics than you just need to add more channel for the same source and connect each channel to a Kafka sink:

```
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1 c2

a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.topic = topic1
...
a1.sinks.k2.channel = c2
a1.sinks.k2.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k2.kafka.topic = topic2
```